# Gold guns on black ops 2

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I am currently working towards getting gold on the SMG's on Call of Duty : Black Ops 2.

I was wondering if there is a special trick or technique that I could use to try to get the gold guns faster?

Any links to guides or tricks you have used yourself would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just kept at it and chipped away at it, in the end for every gun gold, just takes time and dedication.

Comment: There is really not tricks or guides that could be used for this. It all comes down to player skill and luck....mostly luck.

Comment: Like the comments above me said, it just takes time and a bit of luck. One obvious way: always use the gun you are trying to gold out. You never know when you're going to get a bloodthirsty medal and it would be a shame to get one on a gun other than an SMG. One other small tip: I find it goes faster to do the 150 kills with no attachments and no perks at the same time.

Comment: @Nick That is what i have been doing ... i am almost there ... it is just the bloodthirsty's i am having trouble with.

Comment: I find it easy to level up the gun in hardcore

Comment: Time and dedication. Use only the one gun when getting headshots. Through normal gameplay and not trying to get headshots you should get between 1-5 per game. It took me 4Days of game time to get diamond SMGs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there really aren't any ways to get camos quicker, the best and fastest way to get your guns gold is to only use the gun you are trying to get gold.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to get gold is to play on hardcore to get easier headshots. You will soon get used  to it. I got my first gold gun and it took forever until I started playing hardcore or playing with friends. Also use killstreaks like orbital,Uav, or counter spyplane. Those can help you know where the enemies are. Other killstreaks won't help but get you kills. Hope it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

My trick for the headshots is that when you have the aim assist thing on, you aim, then move your sight a little up then shoot. And you will most likely get a headshot. Also you could use a silencer and sneak up behind people and get your headshots like that.  And some of the weapons have a high recoil so at close range shoot at their chest and it will end up hitting their head.

Comment: There are some youtube videos about how to get headshots too those are good sources if you get what they are saying.